# Indentaion in inferior-python-mode

Tags: indentation, python, ipython

In Python mode (python.el), I am in the habit of hitting C-j to return and indent properly. However, when I am in an inferior python buffer, this command only inserts a newline and does not indent. Is there any way to get the inferior-python-mode to work more like python-mode in this respect, or maybe even set up auto-indent the way it normally works in ipython? I have read through the documentation for inferior-python-mode, but can't find anything useful. I love using Emacs for Python, but there are a few pain points, and I am having trouble finding good documentation. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `newline-and-indent` (the function that `C-j` is bound to) inserts a literal newline then whatever would be inserted by `TAB`. What you want is to send the current input:

```el
(defun send-input-and-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (comint-send-input)
  (indent-for-tab-command))
```

Next, bind `send-input-and-indent` to `C-j` only when in inferior-python-mode:

```el
(define-key inferior-python-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'send-input-and-indent)
```

Put both snippets in your initialization file and you're good to go.